# Calculated cells in Telerik RadGrid's GridGroupFooterItem

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm populating a Telerik RadGrid with data from a DataTable (`System.Data.DataTable`). As I'm supporting someone else's application, I can't use any other data source or display control.

In my grid I have three columns: let's say they are Widgets Produced (column A), Faulty Widgets (column B) and Faultiness Proportion (column C). The database query provides these for me and does the calculation C = B / A.

I have a totals row (a Telerik `GridFooterItem`) at the bottom of the grid. In columns A and B Telerik calculates the totals for those columns for me. We can't calculate the correct value for the 'total' of column C from column C alone: we have to populate it with (the sum of B) / (the sum of A).

I've managed to do this by handling the `DataBound` event of the RadGrid and manually populating the cells in the footer. (I had to catch the `GridFooterItem` in the `ItemCreated` event, then put values in it in the `DataBound` event, after it had automatically calculated the totals for A and B for me.) This feels pretty hacky - maybe there's a better way...?

Anyway, the important bit is this:

My grid is split into groups so I also need to populate column C in the `GridGroupFooterItem`s. I can't get my hacky technique to work in this case: I'm finding the footer cell I want with `myGridFooterItem["WidgetsProduced"]`, but I can't get the group footer cells with `myGridGroupFooterItem["WidgetsProduced"]` - it just isn't a dictionary.

I've tried using `myGridGroupFooterItem.Cells[]`, but this `TableCellCollection` contains a couple more cells than I'd expect, so accessing them by integer index feels a tad ropey (especially as this is a user-defined report, so the columns may be in any order).

So: how do I populate these cells with my calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your item databound event looks something like

```
grd_ItemDataBound(object sender,GridItemEventArgs e)
{
//catch the footer element
if(e.Item.ItemType==GridItemType.GroupFooter)
{
    (e.Item.FindControl("yourTextBox") as TextBox).Text = your calculated value
}


}
```

Comment: How do I put a TextBox (or a Literal, preferably) into that cell?

Comment: you would use Footer Template in your grid

from : example in http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdgridtotalswithradnumerictextbox.html

 <FooterTemplate>
                       <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">
                       <ClientEvents OnLoad="Load" />
                       </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                   </FooterTemplate>

Comment: Ah, of course! My grid's being generated dynamically so I'll have to figure out how to create the templates programmatically, but this looks like the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I double-checked whether unique name indexer works with Q2 2009 and Q3 2009 version of RadGrid for ASP.NET AJAX and it worked on my machine. Check your version and ask for more help using the [Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx) if needed.

Dick

Comment: Thanks - yeah, it looks like I'm on 2008 Q2. I'll see if I can get my hands on a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**In Aspx page:**

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn Aggregate="Sum" DataField="Price" DataFormatString="{0:C}" EmptyDataText="0" FooterText="Total :" HeaderText="Price" UniqueName="Price"> ...
```

(Or)

**In Code behind page:**

```
Private Sub RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.ItemDataBound       
    Dim Item As GridDataItem
    Dim value as Double
    Select Case (e.Item.ItemType)
    Case Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemType.AlternatingItem, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemType.EditItem,Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemType.Item,Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemType.SelectedItem

        Item = e.Item
    '------ Calculate Total  amount -----------
        Item("TotalPayment").Text = CDbl(Item("TotalPayment").Text) 
        value += CDec(Item("TotalPayment").Text)

    Case Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemType.Footer
        '------ Display the total  amount in Footer ------
        Dim footerItem As GridFooterItem = e.Item
        If Not RadGrid1.Items.Count = 0 Then footerItem("TotalPayment").Text = "Total :" + value
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you use custom formula to calculate results instead of standard aggregates like sum, average and so on, you probably have to rely on your own logic. The cells from the group footers should be indexable by unique name - I remember this was not supported with previous Telerik ASP.NET Grid versions but this was added in more recent versions - Q2 or Q3 2009.

Dick

Comment: hmm, not sure why -1 . Can you explain ?

Comment: @Ram - the tooltip for down-voting is "This answer is not useful", which I'm afraid describes this answer. In my question I'd said that accessing group footer cells using the UniqueName as an index doesn't work. Maybe this is fixed in later versions, but that doesn't help me, unfortunately.